# Is there a try Convert.ToInt32... avoiding exceptions

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'd like to know if there is a "safe" way to convert an object to an `int`, avoiding exceptions.

I'm looking for something like `public static bool TryToInt32(object value, out int result);`

I know I could make something like this:

```
public static bool TryToInt32(object value, out int result)
{
    try
    {
        result = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        result = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I'd rather avoid exceptions, because they are slowing down the process.

I think this is more elegant, but it's still "cheap":

```
public static bool TryToInt32(object value, out int result)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        result = 0;
        return false;
    }

    return int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);
}
```

Does anyone have better ideas?

UPDATE:

This sounds a little like splitting hairs, but converting an object to string forces the implementer to create a clear `ToString()` function. For example:

```
public class Percentage
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}%", Value);
    }
}

Percentage p = new Percentage();
p.Value = 50;

int v;
if (int.TryParse(p.ToString(), out v))
{

}
```

This goes wrong, I can do two things here, or implement the `IConvertable` like this:

```
public static bool ToInt32(object value, out int result)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        result = 0;
        return false;
    }

    if (value is IConvertible)
    {
        result = ((IConvertible)value).ToInt32(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
        return true;
    }

    return int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);
}
```

But the `ToInt32` method of the `IConvertible` cannot be canceled. So if it's not possible to convert the value, an exception cannot be avoided.

Or two: Is there a way to check if the object contains a implicit operator?

This is very poor:

```
if (value.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name == "op_Implicit" && method.ReturnType == typeof(int)) != null)
{
    result = (int)value;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the TryParse?

Comment: TryParse has a string a parameter.

Comment: I only want to use exception if i'm not expecting one. Here the parameter could be anything. So thats the POV i'm working from.

Comment: Be aware that `Convert.ToInt32` does something different. It tries to cast the object to `IConvertible` and then call the method `ToInt32`. There is a subtle difference: any class could implement `IConvertible`, but could have a `ToString()` that doesn't return a stringified number.

Comment: To your code I would add a check if value is already an int. `if (value is int) return (int)value;`

Comment: @xanatos, i think the IConvertable interface is nice, but the interface won't allow to cancel/try_convert a value. The implementer still needs to throw an exception if a value cannot be converted. _if (value is IConvertible)
            {
                result = ((IConvertible)value).ToInt32(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
                return true;
            }_

Comment: Wow, none of the existing answers adequately answer the question.. I'm too sleepy to write an answer but basically if you're working with primitive integral types use `TypeCode` to determine if input is unsigned `((int)typeCode - 5 & 9) == 1` (assuming you don't care about char and bool) or if it is signed `((int)typeCode  - 5 & 9) == 0` and use `ToUInt64` or `ToInt64` accordingly, then check bounds and profit. All `IConvertible` types implement `GetTypeCode()`. Now of course if you also want to be able to do it for custom types, add your own interface to them, and check for it in the convert.

Comment: Instead of Object.ToString use String.Format with a numeric format specifier, i.e. D, this will not require objects to override default ToString.

Answer (score 59):

```
int variable = 0;
int.TryParse(stringValue, out variable);
```

If it can't be parsed, the variable will be 0. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Comment: This would fail, if you pass an object to TryParse.

Comment: More reliable: `int variable=int.TryParse(stringValue, out variable) ? variable : 0`

Comment: @KaiHartmann: TryParse expects a string not an object. But even if you used an object and called `int.TryParse(myObject.Tostring() , out result)`, it would keep  working for every (non-null) value. The Nullreference exception you'd get for null values has nothing to do with the TryParse, but rather with calling .ToString().

Comment: If `stringValue` equals "0" it will be successfully parsed and `variable` will still be `0`. You should check the return value of `TryParse`.

Comment: The answer from @Rango is the best answer in my use case for now.

Answer (score 16):

Spurring from the comments. The response is **no**. You can't do what `Convert.ToInt32(object)` does without having throwed exceptions. You can do something similar (and you already did it). The only thing I would optimize is the case of `value` already an `int`.

```
if (value is int) 
    return (int)value;
```

You can't do as `Convert.ToInt32(object)` because `Convert.ToInt32(object)` doesn't simply test if `value` is `short, int, long, ushort, ...` and then cast them. It checks if the `value` is `IConvertible`. If yes it uses the `IConvertible.ToInt32`. Sadly the interface `IConvertible` is quite poor: it doesn't have non-throwing methods (`IConvertible.Try*`)

While stupid (but perhaps not too much), someone could make for example a `UnixDateTime` struct: (UnixTime is the number of seconds from midnight 1970-01-01), where the `IConvertible.ToInt32` returns this number of seconds, while the `ToString()` returns a formatted date. All the `int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out parsed)` would choke, while the `Convert.ToInt32` would work flawlessly.

Comment: If we use an IConvertible as parameter in the method instead of object, wouldn't that solve the problem? For an example, see my answer.

Comment: @KaiHartmann Not if you already have an `object`. `object obj = 5.5`. `MyConvert.ToInt32()` would select the `object` overload instead of the `IConvertible` overload.

Answer (score 6):

This version using a type converter would only convert to string as a last resort but also not throw an exception:

```
public static bool TryToInt32(object value, out int result)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        result = 0;
        return false;
    }
    var typeConverter =  System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(value);
    if (typeConverter != null && typeConverter.CanConvertTo(typeof(int)))
    {
        var convertTo = typeConverter.ConvertTo(value, typeof(int));
        if (convertTo != null)
        {
            result = (int)convertTo;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);
}
```

Comment: +1 for being an interesting and different answer. But this really is a *very* roundabout way of using the same old IConvertible methods. Part of the problem here is also the `CanConvertTo` method. It simply doesn't do what we want - we want the answer to depend on the actual value: we want a long to be castable to an int *iff the value stored in that long fits in an int*. This method would throw an overflow exception if trying to cast `long.MaxValue` to an int, because `CanConvertTo` does not do what you think it does, in fact it will return true for **all** primitive types!

Answer (score 5):

No need to re-invent the wheel here. use [int.TryParse](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx&ei=0kcLUuvLDITktQakoYH4BQ&usg=AFQjCNG_gwZKTP6kJQQOBj_WUqJ2NgpOiQ&sig2=xvaXsFR3n-07MhyRcZNtlg&bvm=bv.50723672,d.ZWU) to achieve your goal. It returns a bool to show that value is parsed or not. and if parsed the result is saved in the output variable.

```
int result;
object a = 5;
if(int.TryParse(a.ToString(),out result))
{
   Console.WriteLine("value is parsed");  //will print 5
}    

object b = a5;
if(int.TryParse(b.ToString(),out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine("value is parsed");  
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("input is not a valid integer");  //will print this   
}
```

Comment: This would fail, if you pass an object to TryParse.

Comment: @KaiHartmann yes it needs a string. And if you have object you will have to call the ToString method on that first. updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Return a nullable int.  that way you know whether you parsed 0.

```
int? value = int.TryParse(stringValue, out int outValue) 
    ? outValue
    : default(int?);
```

Comment: Try methods must return bool.

Comment: @user3285954 this TryParse method does.  I'm using a ternary operator.  The boolean that is returned from the TryParse is used to determine whether to return `outValue` or `default(int?)`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a mixture of what you are already doing;

- Check if the object is null - return false and the value 0;
- Attempt to convert directly - if successful, return true and the converted value
- Attempt to parse value.ToString() - if successfull, return true and the parsed value
- Any other case - Return false and the value 0, as object is not convertible/parsible

The resulting code:

```
public static bool TryToInt32(object value, out int result)
{
    result = 0;
    if (value == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Try to convert directly
    try
    {
        result = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        //Could not convert, moving on
    }

    //Try to parse string-representation
    if (Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result))
    {
        return true;
    }

    //If parsing also failed, object cannot be converted or paresed
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why should i pass it as reference?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, Because the result should keep its original value, if it is not converted - I've updated the answer.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, It seems I was mistaken. I will update the answer again. But still, this triple-check seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this mess, looking at it makes me sad.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

internal static class ObjectExt
{
    internal static bool TryConvertToDouble(object value, out double result)
    {
        if (value == null || value is bool)
        {
            result = 0;
            return false;
        }

        if (value is double)
        {
            result = (double)value;
            return true;
        }

        var text = value as string;
        if (text != null)
        {
            return double.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result);
        }

        var convertible = value as IConvertible;
        if (convertible == null)
        {
            result = 0;
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            result = convertible.ToDouble(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = 0;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit
Notice now I answered for double when the question was int, keeping it any way. Maybe useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I like to do it:

```
object v = someValue;
if (int.TryParse($"{v}", out var extractedValue))
{
   // do something with extractedValue
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).