# Using a variable as an out argument at point of declaration

Tags: c#, language-lawyer, out

When reading a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227220/is-there-a-try-convert-toint32-avoiding-exceptions#comment39644756_18227346) to an answer I saw the following construct to declare and initialize a variable:

```
int variable = int.TryParse(stringValue, out variable) ? variable : 0;
```

Is this allowed, correct and well defined in C#?
What happens under the hood? Is the following what happens?

1. Is `variable` first initialized to zero?
2. then passed to `int.TryParse` (which assigns a value)?
3. then optionally read (if `int.TryParse` return `true`)?
4. and then, once again assigned/initialized?

Comment: 1. No (local variables are not assigned by default)

Comment: 2. Yes, *out* means that value will be assigned

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a trick that happens to work because it is simply a rewriting of an ordinary if-statement. This code is equivalent to this:

```
int variable;
if (int.TryParse(stringVariable, out variable))
    variable = variable;
else
    variable = 0;
```

The sequence is as follows:

`int.TryParse` is called, `variable` is not initialized before this but it doesn't have to either. An `out` parameter does not require a definite assigned variable. As part of the method execution, the `variable` will be given a value, and `int.TryParse` will return `true` or `false`.

If the method returns `true` then the result of the *expression*  will be `variable` and thus we will execute basically `variable = variable`.

If the method returns `false` then the result of the *expression*  will instead be `0`, and `variable` will now be given the value `0` regardless of what it was given as part of `int.TryParse`. In this case, however, this will not change the variable because `int.TryParse` has already given the `variable` a default value when it returns `false` which also happens to be `0`.

This is basically a way to get everything onto one line.

Personally I would've written this code like this:

```
int variable;
int.TryParse(stringValue, out variable);
```

Comment: Personally I would have written the code as in your last line, adding an extra line to the extent of `// If TryParse fails it initializes variable = 0.` I am sure that otherwise it would really confuse future me :)

Answer (score 10):

Yes you are right for execution. You can also look into MSIL generated here

C# Code

```
 string stringValue = "5";
 int variable = int.TryParse(stringValue, out variable) ? variable : 0;
```

MSIL generated

```
1.  IL_0000:  nop    
2.  IL_0001:  ldstr      "5" // load string
3.  IL_0006:  stloc.0
4.  IL_0007:  ldloc.0
5.  IL_0008:  ldloca.s   variable
6.  IL_000a:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.Int32::TryParse(string, int32&)
7.  IL_000f:  brtrue.s   IL_0014
8.  IL_0011:  ldc.i4.0
9.  IL_0012:  br.s       IL_0015
10. IL_0014:  ldloc.1
11. IL_0015:  stloc.1
12. IL_0016:  ret
```

Which clarifies what it does behind the scene.

Statement 5 is allocating the variable onto stack.
Statement 6 is calling the method.
Statement 7,8,9 are actually exeuting the bool expression.

Answer (score 5):

`int variable` declares `variable`, and `out variable` necessarily initializes it. Both of these things must happen before `variable` is used anywhere, and because of the `out` declaration, this holds true.

As pointed out by Lasse V. Carlsen, from [TryParse's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx), `TryParse` will by default assign it the value of `0` if the conversion fails:

> When this method returns, [`return`] contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent of the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or **zero if the conversion failed.** (emph. mine)

If you expand the ternary function out, you'd see:

```
int variable;
if (int.TryParse(stringValue, out variable))
    variable = variable;
else
    variable = 0;
```

which is, in and of itself, a legal expression. The two paths are:

- `TryParse` assigns the value to `variable` and returns true, leading to an assignment of `variable` to itself
- `TryParse` initializes `variable` to `0` and returns false, leading to the assignment of `variable` as zero by the ternary condition

This isn't particularly clear code, though, and I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Comment: Actually, if `TryParse` returns `false`, it still has to set `variable`, and in this case it is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) to be initialized to `0`: When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent of the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, **or zero if the conversion failed.** *(my emphasis)*

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks! I've edited that into the answer.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Although `int.TryParse` is documented as always writing the passed-in variable (setting it to zero in case of error), there is in general no guarantee that a function written in another language will write to `out` parameters before returning.  Personally, I think the "try" pattern should have been `T TryComputeSomething(params, out SuccessOrFailure success);`, with the failure case returning `default(T)`. [I'd have `SuccessOrFailure` be a class with defined singletons for success or failure, but supporting the ability to add more info as well].

Comment: Having `TryComputeSomething` return a value of type `T` would make it clear that the failure case returns `default(T)` rather than leaving the argument unmodified, and would also allow for covariance and type inference in ways the `out T` pattern does not.

Comment: @supercat That is true since the CLR does not have the concept of an `out` parameter, only a `ref` parameter, but if a compiler (or programmer) uses a language that allows one to compile a method as one using it as a `ref` parameter and then insists on tucking on the special attribute that makes C# consider it an `out` parameter I daresay that is not a bug in the calling code. In C#, after a call to a method with an `out` parameter, that variable is considered having a value. I'm not sure I like `out` parameters at all though and would probably rather use a type akin to `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Code implementing something like `IDictionary.TryGetValue` in VB.NET will see the signature as `Function TryGetValue(key as TKey, ByRef value as TValue) As Boolean Implements IDictionary.TryGetValue`.  Given that signature, it's hardly obvious that the function should clear `value` if the key is not found, especially since in many cases it would be more useful [though C# wouldn't allow it because `value` is an out-parameter] to leave the value unmodified in such cases (there are many cases where similar libraries I've used in other languages...

Comment: ...like Pascal would allow the pattern `x:=23; TryReading(x, success);` and have `TryReading` either set `x` to the value read or leave it set to 23.)  I suspect the real difficulty stems from the fact that an argument between vb.net and C# designers about whether .NET should recognize `out` parameters was never resolved, but instead both sides simply act as though they won.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't opened Visual Studio to try this, but yes, this is allowed.

It all depends on the "stringValue" variable.  If that is parsable to an integer, `int.TryParse` will return true, and [variable] will have an integer value.  If not, then `variable` will be set to 0.

Does this make for readable code?  Apparently not.